# VBA (and VB6) issue in pasting from Excel to PowerPoint

Tags: vba, excel, vb6, powerpoint

I'm using this code for exporting Excel charts to PowerPoint

```
Sub ChartsToPresentation()

Dim PPApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim PresentationFileName As Variant
Dim SlideCount As Long
Dim iCht As Integer

 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Set PPApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application.16")
 Set PPSlide = PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
 nv = PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex

  ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
  Selection.Copy

 ggg: Set shp =    PPApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(nv).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=0)
 If Err Then GoTo ggg
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

As I'm invoking the sub for many different charts in a loop, I get **often** an error *"Clipboard is empty or contains data which may not be pasted"*. It looks as delay problem between the Copy and the paste.

I'm using Win10 office 2016 64b

Is there a workaround?

I've tried to do it with VB6 but looks the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Use `ppPasteEnhancedMetafile = 2` or `ppPasteShape = 11` or `ppPasteJPG = 5` 
as DataType for charts!

Cleaned and improved code :

```
Sub ChartsToPresentation()
Dim PPApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Set PPApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
Set PPSlide = PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.Slide

ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
DoEvents
PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteShape
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Or take a pick :

[image: members of PpPasteDataType]

Comment: @user3387046 : I edited to include other possibilities.

Comment: Still very unstable. May be caused by the 64B of Office?

Comment: @user3387046 : Unstable how? Nah, the version of Office shouldn't be any issue.

Comment: PowerPoint crashing quite randomly when pasting with datatype:=0

Comment: @user3387046 : Give it a try with `ppPasteShape = 11`